# how to use animation to show the calendar

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I can successfully show the calendar when clicking on the button using property called `alpha`. To show a calendar I am doing

```
calendar.alpha = 5
```

To hide by clicking, I am doing

```
calendar.alpha = 0
```

This is just very simple thing.What I am looking for is some animation to show and hide calendar.

Here's some images

[image]

Above is the textfield and a button. When you click on a button, calendar will show like below
[image]

**Question :**

How can I animate the effect such that it looks like when you are browsing the photo in your Album. If you dont like one of the photo you click `a trash` icon at the bottom right and the photo will slide into the `a trash`. So with this example, when I click on the button, I calendar will slowly show from a button and fully display onto the screen  eventually

*Edit: I think the effect called **suckEffect** in iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That *suck* effect can't be done with Core Animation. To achieve that one, you would need OpenGL.

While that would be a cool effect, it's probably not worth it. Though, I think you might want to add the tag 'opengl' to your question. That might draw the attention of some OpenGL developers who might be able to offer more specific suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

one more thing value of opacity vary from 0-1 you are using 5 its ok but 1 is maximum.

you can also use jquery function like .show() , .hide() or .toggle() method for show hide your calender and animation http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: sorry I am looking for an animation in IOS